# WebClient.DownloadFile issues and Response Header (Vary: negotiate,Pragma: no-cache)

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler

I have a SSIS job where in one of its tasks i use a Script Task (C# code) that tries to download a CSV file (using `WebClient.DownloadFile` Method) from a given website to be processed by later stages.

The download of the CSV would fail every time so in trying to investigating the issue i came across [This Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx) and found that when URL of the CSV File has `Vary: negotiate` and `Pragma: no-cache` in its Response Header then download fails. IE8 is the latest version of IE available on host server so i don't have a say on that. The following error is displayed when trying to download the CSV file using IE8:

[image]

Response Header when trying to download CSV file:

[image]

When i run Fiddler with following Filters the download of CSV works as expected in IE8:

[image]

So my question is how can i do this with `WebClient.DownloadFile` ? I looked into Fiddler.Core but couldn't figure out how to do this. I also looked into simply running Fiddler using:

```
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = @"C:\PROGRA~1\Fiddler2\Fiddler.exe";
```

But problem with the above method is that, when the Process.Kill() is called Fiddler has no chance to cleanup after itself and leaves behind its proxy ...etc resulting of disruption of connectivity for other applications.

Is anyone able to tell me how i can deal with this situation? Thanks

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The .NET WebClient implementation does not suffer from the limitation described in my IEInternals blog post that you cited above. WebClient is based directly on sockets, not WinINET. Your problem has nothing to do with these headers.